# How to install "megamario" ("SDL/SDL.h" not found)

Tags: sdl

I tried to install megamario1.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit
(http://sourceforge.net/projects/mmario/?source=dlp)

I installed all requiered SDL-libraries.

Wenn I type in

```
make PREFIX=/usr/local
```

It gives me the error

```
SDL/SDL.h - no such file ore directory
```

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: /usr/include/SDL/SDL.h <-- the file is there, but megamario won't find it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install also the SDL *development* libraries (that end with `-dev`), like `libsdl1.2-dev`?

OK, so the answer is "yes". Now. The correct way of using the SDL configuration is to use the output from the `sdl-config --cflags --libs` command. This will provide the flags that are necessary for the compiler. Run this command and see what the flags are.

The next step, I'm afraid, is harder: you need to view the `Makefile` and see whether the flags are there, and if not, where to add them.

I downloaded the program and looked at the Makefile: it is simple enough. Just add the --libs flags to the line starting with `LDFLAGS`and the --cflags to the line starting with `CFLAGS`.

Comment: yes, I did... :(
and the files are in /usr/include/SDL/SDL.h - but megamario won't find them there....